# How to convert data from selected user in a dropdown list to a graph form?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of data for loans and deposit that are currently presented on change when a certain user is selected. How to show data in either a graph or pie chart format?

```
function selectUser() {
  updateUserInfo(userAccounts.find((elem) => { return users.value === elem.id; }));
}

function init() {
  userAccounts.forEach((userInfo) => {
      users.innerHTML += `<option value="${userInfo.id}">${userInfo.name}</option>`;
  });
  selectUser();
}

init();
users.addEventListener('change', selectUser)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You can use Google Charts. It's very simple. But there's a lot of alternatives. Just... google.